# While reading text file some lines are not detected?

Tags: python, file, text

> text_file.txt
>
> I am getting the output for first print statement but not for second print statement.Please sugget me the correct code is there anything i have to encode or decode? please help me i m new to python3

Comment: debug with print(line) after if statement to check if the condition is met and after the reassignment of line to check if line contains what you expect, etc.

Comment: please explain and give me the code...how to debug

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/allisonf/how-to-debug-python-code-beginners-print-line-du107ltvx https://pythondebugging.com/articles/python-debugging-with-print-statements

Comment: i am asking few text lines are detected but some are not detected why...

Comment: You're passing the empty string `''` to `lstrip()`, so it will do nothing, as explain in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip).

Comment: you might also have an issue with indentation. both if statements have to be inside the for loop.

Comment: Also, please edit your question and add your expected output. Is it intentional that your first `if` statement skips one line, but your second one doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more straightforward implementation of what you're trying to achieve. You can read the file into a Python list and reference each line by a Python list index

```
with open('text_file.txt','r') as f: # automatically closes the file
    input_file = f.readlines() # Read all lines into a Python list

for line_num in range(len(input_file)):
    if "INBOIS BERCUKAI" in input_file[line_num]:
        print(input_file[line_num + 2]) # offset by any number you want
    # same for other if statements
```

Comment: Thank u so much i got the output